# PHP Get specific Site from steam

Tags: php, parsing, steam

I want to get a specific site from Steam.
URL: 
`http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=730#p1_price_asc`

But file_get_contents seems to ignore the "#p1_price_asc" at the end, so it just uses the URL before the "#".

Is there a way to get this site?

Comment: Just open your browser's dev console and see what requests are being made and replay those exact requests using your http client in php

Comment: The fragment identifier is not sent to the server.  It's used only to scroll the response to the right location in the browser.

Answer (score -1):

Using `file_get_contents`, it is not possible. As `file_get_contents` will not execute javascript, you will get the same content regardless of the content after `#`.

Comment: And what should I use instead?

Comment: Dear downvoter: I was just trying to explain why `file_get_contents` is not appropriate for his case and that no PHP built-in function could help. @PeeHaa comment is an alternative